# Is a volatile boolean switch written to by only one thread thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile

I have the following code:

```
public class Simulation
{       
    public static volatile boolean  IS_EVEN_TICK;
}
```

and the following in another (runnable) class:

```
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // flip the "even/uneven tick" switch
        Simulation.IS_EVEN_TICK = !Simulation.IS_EVEN_TICK;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand it this is generally not thread-safe, because the write to Simulation.IS_EVEN_TICK depends on the current value of that variable. However this thread is the only thread that ever writes to the variable, all other threads will only read the variable (if they access it at all).

Is the variable being volatile enough to make sure that all threads read the right value from it or do I need to synchronize the access to the variable nonetheless?

Comment: [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However this thread is the only thread that ever writes to the variable...  Is the variable being volatile enough to make sure that all threads read the right value from it.

If there is only one writer then there is no race condition.  You do *not* need to synchronize across the variable.

You might consider using an `AtomicBoolean` but it does not support a `toggle()` method so if you had multiple writers toggling the value, you would have to do something like the following:

```
private final AtomicBoolean isEvenTick = new AtomicBoolean();
...
boolean currentValue;
do {
  currentValue = isEvenTick.get();
} while (!isEvenTick.compareAndSet(currentValue, !currentValue);
```

Comment: But what happens if the writing thread gets interrumped in the middle of changing the variable? The reader would get a wrong value at the moment

Comment: Either the reader accesses the boolean _before_ the writer updates it or _after_.  There is always that race @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini.  You can't get away from that, even if you synchronize on it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and precise answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to read [specification](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) and understand JMM, if your variable `volatile` it means that variable will be created directly in heap and no one processor does not copy that value to own cache.

> Volatile fields are special fields which are used for communicating state between threads. Each read of a volatile will see the last write to that volatile by any thread; in effect, they are designated by the programmer as fields for which it is never acceptable to see a "stale" value as a result of caching or reordering

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Gray easy, we are taking about volatile in java

Comment: How does it address his question about race conditions with a single writer when toggling the value?

Comment: @Gray we are talking about that question ? "Is the variable being volatile enough to make sure that all threads read the right value from it or do I need to synchronize the access to the variable nonetheless?"

Comment: I don't see why you would need to argue about this, I wouldn't be asking the question if I hadn't read these things first, would I? I was simply not sure what would happen in my case...

Comment: @LegionaryCohort just as explanation, my answer was yes enough, because you have just a one writing thread. And you know, atomic operations in java are read and write